# react-bootstrap-datetimepicker Icon position

Tags: date, reactjs, datefield

I would to know if anyone knows how to move from right to left the icon used on the right when displaying the bootstrap date field with [react-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker).

I can't find neither in the API doc nor in the [demo](http://dev.quri.com/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/) an example of that?

Thank you